# Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

По словам великого русского писателя И.А.Куприна язык-это история народа, это путь цивилизации и культуры, поэтому изучение и сбережение языка является не праздным занятием, но насущной необходимостью.
Засорение языка иностранными словами серьёзная угроза потери его гибкости, выразительности, способности к передаче тончайших движений человеческий души.
 Русский язык сокровище передаваемое от поколения к поколению и мы обязаны его ценить и беречь.

Comment: @Бела, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось, либо предложите свой вариант ответа.

Comment: Тут видно, что почти всё сделано. Хотелось бы подсказку, все ли знаки припенания и помощь в обьяснений знаков препинания. Я школу давно закончила, уже ничего не помню, сделала, конечно, но не до конца:)

Answer (score 1):

По словам великого русского писателя И.А.Куприна***,*** язык ***-*** это история народа, это путь цивилизации и культуры, поэтому изучение и сбережение языка является не праздным занятием, но насущной необходимостью. Засорение языка иностранными словами ***-***  серьёзная угроза потери его гибкости, выразительности, способности к передаче тончайших движений человеческий души. Русский язык  - сокровище передаваемое от поколения к поколению***,*** и мы обязаны его ценить и беречь.

Comment: А вот и вопрос: не в кавычках ли, так как это цитата. И я думаю, что слово "поэтому" уже новое предложение.

Comment: Нет, "поэтому" поясняет слова Куприна, образуя придаточную часть.  А про "вопрос" не понял. Пожалуйста, поясните, что вы имеете в виду.

Answer (score 1):

Серж все знаки препинания расставил верно, но потерялась запятая после слова "сокровище" в последнем предложении. (причастный оборот). Кроме того, Бела права, что в предложение вставлена цитата, которую надо выделить кавычками.
 По словам великого русского писателя И.А.Куприна, "язык - это история народа, это путь цивилизации и культуры, поэтому изучение и сбережение языка является не праздным занятием, но насущной необходимостью. Засорение языка иностранными словами -серьёзная угроза потери его гибкости, выразительности, способности к передаче тончайших движений человеческий души. Русский язык - сокровище, передаваемое от поколения к поколению, и мы обязаны его ценить и беречь".

Comment: Да, вы правы. После " сокровище"  конечно запятая нужна.Не заметил.

Answer (score 0):

Как это "Поставка знаков препинания"? Поставляются под заказ по предоплате? Предлагаю "расстановка". Однако лучше бы выразить просьбу с использованием глагола: "Помогите расставить знаки". Или что-то в этом роде...

Comment: Это в комментариях надо писать.